# How to write date to ROS2 from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, realm, ros2

I can register user and login using NodeJS.
Next I want to write data to ROS2, I wrote this code refer to [here](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/)
but error occurred.

```
Error: Object type 'Vist' not found in schema.
```

How to write data to ROS2?

```html
const registerUser = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Realm.Sync.User.register(URL, username, password, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    console.log('finish register');
    resolve();
  })
});

const login = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Realm.Sync.User.login(URL, username, password, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(user.token);
  })
});

const registerVisit = (token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const visitSchema = {
    name: 'Visit',
    properties: {
      id: 'int',
      oneday_id: 'string',
      arrival_date: 'string',
      departure_date: 'string',
      latitude: 'double',
      longitude: 'double',
      is_hidden: 'bool',
    }
  };

  Realm.open({ schema: [visitSchema] })
    .then(realm => {
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.create('Vist', {
          id: 1,
          oneday_id: "ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP-QRST",
          arrival_date: "2017-11-05 11:11:11",
          departure_date: "2017-11-05 22:22:22",
          latitude: 23.1234567,
          longitude: 12.34567,
          is_hidden: false,
        });
      });
      resolve();
    })
    .catch(err => reject(err));
});

login()
  .then(() => registerVisit())
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

As far as I looked document, There is no document about how to write data.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: ah sory @EpicPandaForce
I added code just now.

Comment: You typed `Vist` instead of `Visit`

Comment: wtf my code... thanks @EpicPandaForce ... :-)